# Designing Viewmodels and avoid if else statements in controllers and write good business logic asp.net web api using design patterns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

I have a web api action method which takes below Model as parameter (Post).

```
 public class RequestModel
 {
    public string PartType { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost{ get; set; }
    public bool? Owner { get; set; }
    public bool? DoSplit { get; set; }
 }
```

The options Owner/Do Split will be choosen by the user on UI and its based on Part Type. Also based on the Owner flag there is some other business logic which needs to be executed in combination with the DoSplit and Quantity. Hence I have many permuations and combinations. Going bruteforce the logic would go this way:

```
int existingQty = GetInitialQuantity(model.SerialId); //returns esisting qty 
if(existingQty < model.Quantity && model.Owner)
{
  // logic here
}
else if (existingQty < model.Quantity && model.Owner == false)
{

}
else if (existingQty = model.Quantity) // no need to check for DoSplit
{
}
etc..... more if else in combincation with qty comaprison, Dosplit and owner  flag checks with null checks.
```

based on the different property values in the model (in combination) I need to do different actions. How to avoid if else and use a proper design patterns of C# here.
Since the model is passed from javascript through a web api call to my action method how can I use OOPs here for the requestmodel and avoid branching in the controller method ?

Comment: "How to avoid if else and use a proper design patterns of C# here" - there is nothing wrong with using `if {} else`. Where are you getting this idea from?

Comment: There are patterns like Visitor and Decorator which help to avoid if else and write c# in tell dont ask principle.

Comment: Using if/else is actually considered a code smell by some programmers. And if you look at the ammount of if/else in this post you can see why. I have the believe you can programm without if/else and you should do that, as if/else violates a lot of important principles, for example open close principle or in some cases single responsibility principle. A state pattern is a nice way to get rid of if/else. But right now there is too few code to be able to tell you how to remove it. How does the client use this class?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the main reasons that you have so much if/else is that you do not have the business logic in the object itsel but try to use the business logic from outside. As I do not get what your business logic is, my implementation might not work on your case, but i want to show you how to get rid of the if else in a simple case. The main goal is to not use the properties but only use the functions and let the object handle its state on its own. (lookup Tell dont ask and State Pattern)

lets look at this class

```
public class User
{
    string name { get; set; }
    bool isDisabled { get; set; }
}
```

using it might be like this

```
if (!user.isDisabled)
{
    user.name = nameFromApi
}
```

but in this case you have to repeat this on every corner where you want to use the User. So consider this

```
public interface IUser
    {
        string name { get; }
        IUser updateName(string newName);
        IUser disableUser();
    }


    public class DisabledUser : IUser
    {
        public DisabledUser(IUser activeUser)
        {
            this.name = activeUser.name;
        }

        public string name { get; }
        public IUser updateName(string newName)
        {
            return this;
        }

        public IUser disableUser()
        {
            return new DisabledUser(this);
        }
    }

    public class ActiveUser : IUser
    {
        public ActiveUser(IUser user)
        {
            this.name = user.name;
        }
        public string name { get; private set; }

        public IUser updateName(string newName)
        {
            this.name = newName;
            return this;
        }

        public IUser disableUser()
        {
            return new DisabledUser(this);
        }
    }
```

In this way the if is gone and you actually gained something else: You can easily extend the implementation with other states like banned and you do not have to change the old implementation. Yes, it is more code, but way easier to maintain.
In you case i think you should be able to get rid of all the if/elses regarding the boolean flags, if you initialize the objects correctly. This is a powerfull pattern and you do not need to cast anything to be able to use the user. 
I do not know your usecase for the quantity stuff, so I can not tell you how this might get resolved, but there is certainly a way to do that.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. The RequestModel calss in my case is the ViewModel which gets binded when someone calls the api method. For ex: Lets the say my action method is public bool ServicePart(RequestModel reqModel){ }. The class is initialized from the javascript , so can I have a IRequestModel interface instead of RequestModel class to the action method in a web API ??

Comment: Can you give an example what happens in the if else branches? And why do you post it, is it supposed to change something or create a new RequestModel? And no, you can not post an interface (as far as I am concerned), but you can load the Model to the ID and use the interface.